# Is there a way to fake operator overloading in Typescript

Tags: typescript, operator-overloading

I'm writing a game with physics in Typescript and Pixi.js and I'm starting to notice that going from a vector2 to a PIXI.Point or doing calculations with them truly is hell without operator overloading.

Is there any way to fake operator overloading with Typescript?  And would it be possible at all due to the nature of javascript?

Comment: TS will not support behavior JS does not support, JS does not support operator overloading .. so basically no, you are stuck with methods ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir “TS will not support behavior JS does not support” — I mean, that’s obviously untrue, since TS extends JS. It’s entirely conceivable for TS to provide operator overloading that compiles down to valid JS, the authors just decided against it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nope, not gonna happen at leas not as things stand. It is explicitly something that the TS team avoids, adding new things to expression land (ie stuff that makes it into JS). During their 'young' days they added enums and namespaces but since then they have been very consistent about not adding new runtime behavior. They stick to types. See non-goals: "Provide additional runtime functionality " https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals . Not saying it can't ever ever ever happen, but as things stand now, it won't

Comment: FYI: keep an eye on this proposal : https://github.com/littledan/proposal-operator-overloading/ :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir They also added `class XY {constructor(public x = 0, public y = 0) {}}` which adds a bunch of extra `this.x = x`-like statements aswell. So they are long done with the "only remove types" thing. Operator overloading sooner or later will arrive, since JS devs require it for various reasons and QuickJS already has it implemented.

Comment: @kungfooman That is debatable. The syntax you are referring to is actually from when TS started out, when they were actually more open to adding syntax with runtime behaviors, enums, namespaces are also examples of this. This has changes significantly since tc39 actually started to work and is adding new features to JS.